# Python, Arima prediction out of sample

Tags: python, prediction, statsmodels, data-fitting

I am trying to use ARIMA model fitted by `arima_mod = sm.tsa.ARIMA(residual, (p,d,q)).fit(trend="c",maxiter = 20)` for out of sample prediction of the next value in the residual series. To to that, I may apply one of the following:

```
next_pred1 = arima_mod.predict(start,end,dynamic=True)[-1]
next_pred2 = arima_mod.predict(start,end,dynamic=False)[-1]
```

The results of both predictions are bad. Correction - with `dynamic=False` these are bad. With `dynamic=True` these are horrible. I am trying to understand why: when I set start to distant past and end to the next value (which is out of sample), the prediction is bad but at least is does not change between different values. I.e., for start = 4 and for start = 8 the prediction will give the same output (I have about 40 samples to base the prediction on). When I set the same start/end values and use dynamic=True, the output gets worse given more past. Which does not make sense - for ARIMA - (2,0,2) the prediction should only use the estimate of the last 2 values with the dynamic setting, but it seems that it uses all past samples for forecasting. The output value is suddenly 1E-20 rather than, say 0.15 or 1.1... It is as if a strange (weighted by p or similar) approximation of the mean of the series is used for the prediction...
Please advise - how many samples should I take back for forecasting of the next out-of-sample value with ARIMA = (p,d,q)? The last p values only? Else? Why do the results of the prediction are so bad (model trained on 40 values - is this not "sufficiently enough" for small p and q? I know that more values the better, but this is all I have). 
Your advice will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about `dynamic`. "dynamic=True" means it only uses information from before the `start` date. So you are trying to predict the 41st value based on the first 4 resp. 8 observations. ARIMA results has a `forecast` method to predict out of sample at the end of the estimation periods as a simpler interface than predict. http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResults.forecast.html

Comment: Another clarification: prediction is based on the available past values. If there is a MA term, then the residual will be calculated from the beginning of the sample. So, in this case it doesn't just use the last p values.

Comment: Thank you. There is something I find strange though - predict that uses the entire sequence with "dynamic = False" should provide results equivalent to ".forecast". This is not the case in the example on which I tried all 6 possibilities ("dynamic = False" using css, mle or css-mle criteria Vs predict for each matching criterion) - the results of the prediction differ both for the False and the True (tried that too) dynamics comparing to the .forecast ... What is a possible explanation for that? The level of alpha perhaps? Thanks again

Comment: I also think that `... predict that uses the entire sequence with "dynamic = False" should provide results equivalent to ".forecast".`  But, I always forget the details, if I knew them. If there is a difference larger than numerical noise, then the residual sequence might not be exactly the same. That requires checking the code used for the two cases. Did you check that you have the correct dates of the forecast? I would need a reproducible example in a github issue to check.